Term in double pendulum derivation
I'm working through a particular derivation of the equation of motion of a double pendulum of two points masses m1 and m2 with lengths $l_1$ and $l_2$ using angles off vertical $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ as the coordinates.

I haven't done this without Lagrange's equation in quite a while, so I'm a bit rusty on the Newtonian approach. The author of this particular derivation says they take the moments about the origin to get :
$$
m_1 l_1^2 \ddot{\theta_1} = m_1 g l_1 \theta_1 + m_2 l_1 (\theta_2 - \theta_1) 
$$
after some reduction and the small angle approximation, all of which is straight forward.
The moments about mass 1 (which is moving) contains a term that I'm having trouble with. They list the following as the sum of the moments about the $m_1$ mass.
$$
m_2 l_2^2 \ddot{\theta_2} + m_2 l_2 (l_1 \ddot{\theta_1}) = -m_2 g(l_2 \sin{\theta_2})
$$
I know that the $ m_2 l_2 (l_1 \ddot{\theta_1}) $ has something to do with the fact that we are taking the sum of the moments about the moving $m_1$ reference fame, but can't recall or find what that term physically represents or from where it could be derived. If someone could explain where that term comes from, I'd be able to sleep tonight. Thanks.

Something is wrong with your equations . The equations are:
$~(m_1+m_2),l_1^2\ddot\theta_1+m_2,l_1,l_2\ddot\theta_2=-(m_1+m_2),g,l_1,\theta_1~$
$~m_2,l_2^2\ddot\theta_2+ m_2,l_1,l_2\ddot\theta_1=-m_2,g,l_2,\theta_2$

It's a ficticious force term as you can see in this link. In particular, for an object moving about an accelerating reference frame B, it's the term (where A is the inertial reference frame, in this case, the origin)
$$-m\mathbf{a}_{AB}. $$
The acceleration here is the acceleration of B as observed in the inertial frame A. The link has a more extensive derivation of all the ficticious forces involved (check the "General derivation" section). This particular term appears as
$$|\tau_{\mathrm{fict}}|=|\mathbf{r}\times \mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{fict}}|=m_2l_2(l_1\ddot{\theta}_1)$$
where obviously the acceleration of the moving frame (mass 1) is $l_1\ddot{\theta}_1$.
Physically, it's the same "force" that you feel when you're in an accelerating car or some other vehicle. The objects within the car are not accelerating with it (initially) and so in their reference frame, it's as if a force is acting on them, when it's just a byproduct of the car's acceleration.
